# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]!

Tags: android-studio

So I am doing a little something in Android and this error comes up:
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

I cant install the app please help! My AndroidManifest is follow: Please have a look and help me!

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"
    />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    == <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: if you have a "malformed manifest" it might help to post your error and the manifest...

Answer (score 0):

My bad I had not added the Name-Value pair for Meta Data (Value part) so the meta data had only Name and no values. When I deleted all the meta datas I resolved it for now.

Thanks